# Как добавить новую строку, а не перезаписать json файл в юнити?

Tags: c#, unity3d

есть код:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Data : MonoBehaviour
{

    public class SaveData
    {
        public string name;
        public string secondName;
        public string city;
        public string phone;
        public string email;
        public string place;
    }

    public TMP_InputField TMPname;
    public TMP_InputField TMPsecondName;
    public TMP_InputField TMPcity;
    public TMP_InputField TMPphone;
    public TMP_InputField TMPemail;
    public TMP_InputField TMPplace;

    public void OnClickSave()
    {
        var data = new SaveData()
        {
            name = TMPname.text,
            secondName = TMPsecondName.text,
            city = TMPcity.text,
            phone = TMPphone.text,
            email = TMPemail.text,
            place = TMPplace.text
        };

        var json = JsonUtility.ToJson(data);
        File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "SaveData.json"), json);
        Debug.Log("Data saved");
    }
}
```

Подскажите, что нужно сделать, чтобы новые данные не перезаписывали файл, а добавлялись новой строкой в него

Comment: JSON это цельная структура данных, вы не должны хотеть дописать в файл новую строку, вы должны хотеть прочитать **все** текущие данные в набор классов, изменить этот набор классов, а затем записать **весь** набор классов в файл, **заменив все данные** в файле. Сейчас я вижу, что вы не читаете старые данные, а лишь записываете новые, вот с этого и начните, десериализуйте JSON в класс, измените его, а затем сериализуйте обратно в JSON.

Comment: `File.AppendAllText`, только для JSON такое не подходит. Прилинковал ответы на похожие вопросы вверху.

Comment: Обратите внимание на [JSON Lines](https://jsonlines.org/). В этом формате каждая строка является отдельным json, что позволяет дописывать новые данные в конец. Этот формат уже довольно распространён.

Comment: Всем спасибо за комменты, буду работать в этих направлениях